# In-plot axis text in ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm new to ggplot2, and I have a bar plot of mean responses that I Frankensteined out of sample code.

dput() output to reproduce graph:

```
> dput(mainerrors.df)
structure(list(sex = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Male", 
"Female"), class = "factor"), condition = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("Weather", "Negative", "Positive"
), class = "factor"), N = c(19, 18, 26, 55, 50, 49), willingness = c(5.47368421052632, 
5.48148148148148, 5.97435897435897, 6.37575757575758, 5.88666666666667, 
6.2312925170068), sd = c(1.3067525929499, 1.41524021482219, 1.05797742854762, 
0.865560893471263, 1.13611104180873, 0.969927645336604), se = c(0.299789605098861, 
0.333575317636226, 0.207486444350194, 0.116712207066377, 0.160670364368774, 
0.138561092190943), ci = c(0.629834588787353, 0.703782401529606, 
0.427326331312926, 0.233993886626096, 0.32287918557602, 0.278595748013486
)), .Names = c("sex", "condition", "N", "willingness", "sd", 
"se", "ci"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Code to reproduce graph:

```
figure.4 <- ggplot(mainerrors.df, aes(x = condition, y = willingness)) +
                facet_wrap(~sex) +
                geom_bar(stat="identity", colour="black", aes(fill=sex)) +
                geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=willingness-ci, ymax=willingness+ci),
                              size=.3,
                              width=.2,
                              position=position_dodge(.9)) +
                scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set3", name="Sex",
                                  breaks=c("Male", "Female"),
                                  labels=c("Male", "Female")) +
                scale_x_discrete("Peer Comment Frame") +
                scale_y_continuous("Willingness to use a condom (95% CI)", breaks=1:7)
                theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", colour = NA),
                      legend.position = "none",
                      axis.text.x = element_text(size=16),
                      axis.text.y = element_text(size=16),
                      axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold", colour="#7f7f7f", size=16, vjust=0.1),
                      axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold", colour="#7f7f7f", size=16),
                      strip.text.x = element_text(size = 16, colour = "black"))
```

Everything looks very nice, except I can't get the axis titles the way I want them no matter how much I play with vjust. So I thought: why not put the axis titles in the plot itself, instead of hanging way out there? The facet titles are a perfect example of how I would like my graph to look (it seems I can't post images directly): http://postimg.org/image/cnma6zp99/

I would like the x-axis/y-axis titles to run along the bottom/left side of the plot like Male/Female does at the top, because it would look much more coherent and avoid all the positioning issues. Is there any way to do this (or a way to control axis title positioning more precisely than vjust allows, but this would be optimal)?

EDIT: I photoshopped together a rough example of how I'm envisioning my graph: 
[image]

Comment: Hi there! Please make your post reproducible. Read the post [**how to make a great reproducible example**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on how to do this. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry about that! I will get on it ASAP. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: There is probably no way to achieve what you ask without quite some effort in customized grid graphics code. Possible, but probably not worth the effort.

Comment: Thanks for saving me the time. I guess I'll go find out how to make a suggestion to ggplot2!

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear waht do you want to do , but here a start of a solution inspired from @baptiste. solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070953/photo-alignment-with-graph-in-r/14071840#14071840). The main idea is to define a custom element to hold the customization of x and y titles. The solution is far from being finished but it shows the idea. You can also use lattice. This kind of customization is simple withe the `lattice` package.

[image]

```
require(ggplot2)
require(grid)

# user-level interface to the element grob
my_axis = function(text,rot=0) {
  structure(
    list(text=text,rot=rot),
    class = c("element_custom","element_blank", "element") # inheritance test workaround
  )
}
# returns a gTree with two children: the text label, and a rasterGrob below
element_grob.element_custom <- function(element,...)  {
  g2 <- rectGrob(gp=gpar(fill='red',alpha=0.5))
  g1 <- textGrob(element$text, x=0.5,vjust=0.5,rot  =element$rot)
  gTree(children=gList(g2,g1), cl = "custom_axis")
}
# gTrees don't know their size and ggplot would squash it, so give it room
 grobHeight.custom_axis = heightDetails.custom_axis = function(x, ...)
   unit(1, "lines")


ggplot(mtcars,aes(mpg,disp))+geom_point()+facet_grid(.~vs)+
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.title.x = my_axis('my custom x title'),
        axis.title.y = my_axis('my custom y title',rot=90))
```

Comment: That looks almost exactly what I was looking for, provided I can manage to position the red bars within the plot itself somehow! Thanks for the help, I'll play around with this for a bit and see what turns up. I'd upvote you, but apparently I can't because I have no rep? Harsh.

Comment: I mean the red rectangles with the axis titles, sorry.

Comment: I've added an example I photoshopped together to show what I mean more clearly. Currently I'm just trying to figure out how to prevent ggplot from squeezing the y-axis rectangle.