# Adding images below x-axis labels in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggtext

I have this plot:

[image: my plot]

Which has been produced with this code chunk based on an old TidyTuesday dataset, Astronaut.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)

astro_Q2_final %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(nationality, proportion), y = proportion)) +
  geom_col() +
  theme_minimal() +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(proportion, 3)), position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), 
            vjust = -0.25) +
  labs(title = "Proportion of Space Travellers who are Female, by Nationality",
       x = "Nationality",
       y = "Proportion of Female Astronauts")
```

The data itself is quite simple - character variable of nationality on the x-axis, and an integer variable corresponding to a worked-out proportion on the y. All I want to do is add images of the flags of the nationalities on the x-axis above the country names. I have tried this [photo alignment with graph in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070953/photo-alignment-with-graph-in-r/30652364#30652364) but with no luck; I think it's something to do with the fact that Claus Wilke creates the `data` object with the `expand.grid` function - I can't seem to translate what he's doing to what I need to do with my plot/data. Any help would be much appreciated.

The data can be found here https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gjpstrain/astro/main/data.csv

So I've had another look at the ggtext documentation and have included this:

```
labels <- c(
  U.S.S.R/Russia = "<img src = 'Russia.png' width = 100' /><br>USSR/Russia",
  China = "<img src = 'China.jpg' width = '100' /><br>China",
  Italy = "<img src = 'Italy.png' width = '100' /><br>Italy",
  France = "<img src = 'France.jpg' width = '100' /><br>France",
  U.S = "<img src = 'US.png' width = '100' /><br>US",
  Japan = "<img src = 'Japan.png' width = '100' /><br>Japan",
  Canada = "<img src = 'Canada.png' width = '100' /><br>Canada",
  U.K = "<img src = 'UK.png' width = 100' /><br>UK",
  Korea = "<img src = 'South-Korea.jpg' width = '100' /><br>Korea")
```

However when I try this:

```
astro_Q2_final %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(nationality, proportion), y = proportion)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_x_discrete(name = NULL,
                   labels = labels)
```

I get [image: this]

Comment: Can you help make this a reproducible question so that others can test and verify potential solutions? e.g. can you give an example of data that has the same form as `astro_Q2_final`, and images?   Does the example at https://github.com/wilkelab/ggtext  help?

Comment: I have added the data to my Git and linked it. The images are a mix of .jpg and .png files hosted in the same folder as my .rproj file

Comment: I have tried replicating the example on the ggtext documentation, but I can't get the image to appear, whether it's calling it locally or from a url

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load library `ggtext` and add this line in the last

```
astro_Q2_final %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(nationality, proportion), y = proportion)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_x_discrete(name = NULL,
                   labels = labels) +
  theme(axis.text.x = ggtext::element_markdown())
```

You should get the desired visual, if the image-links are correct.